# Why does eBay keep sending me "daily deals" emails?

Tags: spam-prevention, ebay

I changed my notification preferences on the eBay website to stop sending me spam some time ago. It does say that the changes can take up to 10 days, but believe me, I unticked everything well past that and still receive emails.

I have nothing ticked under "Promotions and Surveys":

[image]

It's really annoying!

Comment: It's actually against the law for them to continue to send emails after unsubscribing. This is probably a manual process on their end but in order to be CAN-SPAM Compliant it has to get done. They aren't doing their job here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get these "Daily Deals" mails too; I think eBay mails them to any active eBay users.

Ebay's privacy policy is here as "Privacy Central"

http://pages.ebay.com/help/privacycentral2.html

(The privacy policy links to `My eBay > My Account > Preferences > Notification Preferences` but I don't see anything relevant there, mostly that's buying and selling emails you would actually *want*...)

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you're in `My eBay > Account > Communication Preferences` with the `Promotions and Surveys` heading expanded. In my case I **did** have some of those checked! I turned them off. Based on that, it seems you shouldn't be getting the emails, and you're in the correct place.

You might have to contact eBay support if the emails continue, or just set up a spam filter for them.

Comment: I've got none checked.  At one point I was able to get rid of some going to one email, then they found another email.  There's no value to any of it, just pure make you mad useless spam.  I don't get why they would want people to hate them.  It's way too often and too useless for anyone to be interested in that much of it.

Answer (score 5):

I've been getting the same emails.

Instead of an unsubscribe link, there's this paragraph at the bottom of the email:

> You are subscribed as XXX registered on eBay. To change your communication preferences, log into My eBay and select the Account tab, then click on 'Communication Preferences'. Please note that it may take up to 5 business days to process your request.

I didn't want to do this.

Instead, I found (by trial and error) that if you take the link at the top of the email that says:

> Can't see the pictures? Select "Always display images" or <view this message in your browser>.

Copy the link URL for viewing the email in your browser. It should look like this:

```
http://mail.ebay.com.au/r/mail/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Change it to:

```
http://mail.ebay.com.au/r/unsubscribe/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

It shows an "Unsubscribe Successful" message.

Answer (score 2):

I got these mails too even though I had all notifications disabled and found out that they were spoofed mails.. If I clicked "open this mail in a webbrowser" I was taken to a non-ebay domain (p0.com). Also viewing the HTML source of the mail revealed a non-ebay domain (4at5.net). Talked to Ebay chat support about this and they confirmed that the mails were spoofed. Anyway, if this is the situation and you get spoofed mails like this you can forward them to spoof@ebay.com so they can take appropriate actions.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case here. Checking the e-mail headers reveals that my e-mails are indeed from eBay. I am still getting e-mails over two weeks after I disabled the preferences, so I set up an e-mail rule to delete them automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it:

1. Click My eBay at the top of most eBay pages. You may have to sign in.
2. Click the Account tab.
3. Click "Communication Preferences" (link is on the left side of page).
4. Scroll to the bottom to the section labeled "Promotions and Surveys". (Click "Show All" to expand the selection). You'll probably see that all options are checked off (surveys, promotions, etc.)
5. Un-click all or whichever ones you want.
6. Click "Save" and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with eBay today after I terminated my account with them. I was told that changes and deletion won't change for 180 days!!! My customer "service" rep told me that I will continue to receive unsolicited emails for another 6 months. This annoyed the hell out of me and I asked to speak with a supervisor only to be told that because I'm not a member, I have no access. Basically, to make a long story short my options are this: 1) too bad so sad, 2) cancel that email address, 3) write a letter to them on my own dime.

Answer (score 1):

Open an Ebay Deals email in your browser, you will find that the email is "Clipped"
Click show entire email and you will find there is more at the bottom of the message, including the unsubscribe button.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a legit email from ebay there will be some very small fine print at the bottom that has an unsubscribe link. **BE CAREFUL** if it is not a legit email then you need to avoid clicking any and all links - avoid like the plague in fact.

The legit link will be to `http://dailydeal.ebay.com/unsubscribe.jsp` and there will be a parameter after that part that will look similar to `?s=ZJqd&i=581188148513` (the value after the ?s= will be unique to your email).

The absolute safest way is to open a browser and type everything into the address bar by hand `http://dailydeal.ebay.com/unsubscribe.jsp?s=*yourcode*` using the the code that is in your email's link (mouse over the link and it will show you the url that the link points to without needing to actually click on it.)

Once your on that page you should just need to click a confirm button then close the browser.

BTW My communication settings were cleared too - for some reason this Ebay Daily Deals email is "extra special" and makes its way through in spite of the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am frustrated as well. I checked all the communications and ad preferences and all looks checked.  I found this one extra step that I hope will stop the email but here is what I did today:

1. Click on the "View entire message" on the bottom of the emmail where i says "[Message clippped] View entire message".
2. A new browser tab opened with the entire message which shows the "unsubscribe" link at the very bottom of the entire email:
   "If you do not wish to receive further communications like this, please unsubscribe. Alternatively, you can change your Notification Preferences in My eBay. Please note that it may take up to 10 days to process your request."
3. This will bring you to the UNSUBSCRIBE page where you can click and get a notification that your email preferences have been changed.